# Get bindiff of operating system or modified files post upgrade

Tags: windows, patch-reversing, operating-systems, bin-diffing

I am wanting to examine changes made to Windows after an update is made. I would like to see the actually files that were patched and see what in the code might have been changed and see what the problem was.

So if windows updates MS0xxx buffer overflow. I would like to see what the problem was and what was changed to fix it.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to see the actually files that were patched ...

- Old-school: [Winalysis](http://download.cnet.com/Winalysis/3000-2162_4-10047818.html)
- New-school: [Attack Surface Analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_Surface_Analyzer)

> ... and see what in the code might have been changed and see what the problem was.

As @Neitsa said, see [how can I diff two x86 binaries at assembly code level?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1879/how-can-i-diff-two-x86-binaries-at-assembly-code-level)

Comment: Cannot seem to find the gui version to produce a product . Still looking though.

Comment: GUI version of what?

Comment: Attack Surface Analyzer

Comment: You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24487. That page also has instructions on how to use the tool and how to analyze the results.